# Executing python functions with multiple arguments in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a python function which takes multiple arguments and i want it to run from terminal but it's not working. what am I doing wrong?

counting.py script:

```
def count (a, b): 
    word = False 
    a = " " + a + " "
    b = " " + b + " "

    result = 0 

    for i in range (len (a)-1): 
        if a[i] == " " and a[i+1] != " ":
            word = True 
            result += 1
        else: 
            word = False

    for i in range (len (b)-1): 
        if b[i] == " " and b[i+1] != " ":
            word = True 
            result += 1
        else: 
            word = False


    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    count (a, b)
```

terminal command:

```
    python counting.py count "hello world" "let's check you out"
```

Comment: How is Python supposed to know that `count(a,b)` means that those are program arguments?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this is what i wanna understand. how to tell python this

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

useing `sys` model,
add this code, the sys.argv first parameter is this file name

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2]
    count(a,b)
```

terminal command: 
`python counting.py "hello word" "let's check you out"`
ex:

```
import sys
def count(s1, s2):
    print s1 + s2

print sys.argv
count(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

out:

> python zzzzzzz.py "hello" "word"

```
['zzzzzzz.py', 'hello', 'word']
helloword
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are the arguments of `count`. You cannot use them outside that scope. You could instead use `sys.argv` to access the commandline arguments:

```
from sys import argv
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count (argv[1], argv[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others using `sys`:

```py
from sys import argv

def count(a, b):
    return len(a.split(" ")) + len(b.split(" "))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = argv[1]
    b = argv[2]
    
    word_count = count(a, b)
    print(word_count)
```

**Or**, you could use the built-in module `argparse`. In case you ever have a more complex script taking arguments from the console.

```py
import argparse

def count(a, b):
    return len(a.split(" ")) + len(b.split(" "))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Word Count")
    parser.add_argument("-a", type=str, help="First Sentence")
    parser.add_argument("-b", type=str, help="Second Sentence")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    word_count = count(args.a, args.b)
    print(word_count)
```

Execute your script with `python counting.py -a "hello world" -b "let's check you out"`.

And if you execute `python counting.py -h`, you'll get a nicely formatted help for the users:

```sh
usage: counting.py [-h] [-a A] [-b B]

Word Count

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A        First Sentence
  -b B        Second Sentence
```